# Ruby - Running rb file from script

Tags: ruby, file

I'd like to write a ruby script that then calls another ruby script.
Example, I'd like to run the "test1.rb" from my script.
The test1.rb has been simplified to just do this:

```
print "1"
```

Then get the result (-> 1).

I tried to complete this problem with backticks or another executing command (%x[#{"test1.rb"}], system("test1.rb") etc.), but it didn't work.

So any idea how I call one script that then calls another script (either relinquishing total control or forking), and get the results?

Thanks

Comment: what did `system("test1.rb")` do? Did you try this with full (absolute) path to `test.rb`?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? I'm guessing your attempt failed for the same reason typing `test1.rb` on the command line won't work: `test1.rb` isn't an executable file. You either need to execute the script with Ruby (e.g. `system("ruby", "test1.rb")`) or make the file executable with `chmod` and adding a shebang line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use open3

```
require 'open3'
cmd = 'ruby test1.rb'
#You may change the contents of cmd like you would run it from the command line; like ruby [directory]/filename
Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout|
  var = stdout.read
  puts var
end
```

Comment: This might actually be what @huri.ferenc needs.

Comment: I think it's a very nice script.

Comment: I tried this, but returns an error message: "Can't find the file (1)"

Comment: Sorry, the error message correctly:

Comment: this will work if the ruby script is on the same directory with the one calling it. I'll edit the code

Comment: "X:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open3.rb:193:in `spawn': No such file or directory
- ruby teszt1.rb (Errno::ENOENT)"

Comment: It's weird because the main and test1 file are on the same directory.

Comment: have you changed the script to suit your needs? It's working fine by me :) are you sure about the name of the file? its spelled teszt1.rb... might be a typo

Comment: Ok, the path was not correct, but now it's fixed.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be of help :)

Comment: +1 Because you solved OPs issue, but it's still a very dirty thing to do. Evaluating Ruby files you don't have controll over and trying to evaluate the "puts" sounds like serious hacking to me...

Answer (score 4):

You can simply require the file, which would load the code and execute it:

```
require_relative "path/test1"
```

For the sake of having controll over the the run code, I would advice to place your script in a method:

```
# In test1.rb
def exec_my_script
 puts 1
end

# In your main script
require_relative "path/test1"
exec_my_script
```

---

**EDIT**: Ok, since this does not seem to work for your usecase, you can read the file as string and eval the string as so:

```
result = eval(File.read("path/test1.rb"))
# do something with result
```

I do NOT like this approach, because it feels kinda "hacky" and is by all means insecure and it will only work if the last thing called in your test1 script returns the result you need...

Comment: I really can't imagine that you would want to do this any other way. +1

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea, but I can't modify the test files.

Comment: I must call more same test files in the script and get the results after running.

Answer (score 0):

```
system('ruby test1.rb') # should do the trick
```

You can also make test1 executable (with [chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)) and add the shebang line on top of test1.

You then can call

```
system("./test1.rb")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the system('ruby test1.rb') and system("ruby", "test1.rb") command worked.

And now, I like to set the returning value ("1") to a variable.

How I do it? It's possible to do that with backticks?